# In site.com how do I include a site custom property in a javascript file?

Tags: site.com

I just want to include a custom property in a javascript file. Seems like there must be something obvious I'm missing.

```
               // Javascript ...
                if (funPrms.en == 'QAE')
                    funnel.config.url = '{!QAE_Server}'+funnel.config.funnelname;
                else if (funPrms.en == 'UAT')
                    funnel.config.url = '{!UAT_Server}'+funnel.config.funnelname;
```

But the custom property value I've defined in my Custom Properties is not replacing the {!QAE_Server}

---

So as I mention below (thank you Ricksmt), it turns out Site.com considers 'assets' (stylesheets, scripts, etc.) don't get processed, so your {!} variables are never parsed. What I did to get around this is to use the Configure Scrips option on the page and edit the  to add this code:

```
<script> 
/* Set Environment Servers */ 
devServer = '{!DEV_Server}'; 
qaeServer = '{!QAE_Server}'; 
uatServer = '{!UAT_Server}'; 
</script>
```

Then I can use these global variables in my function calls lower down the page. Not perfect, but will work for my purposes on this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

External Javascript, CSS, and other files are not processed by the server. The server processes expressions when retrieving a Visualforce page or component.

I'm facing a similar issue myself. I've got a custom font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: customFont;
    src: url({!URLFOR($Resource.Fonts, customFont.woff)});
}
```

I can't put this in a style sheet because I need Salesforce to process the URLFOR. To avoid redeclaring it everywhere, I'm putting it into a Visualforce component with some other stuff I need Salesforce to process. Then I'll just include the component and use the pieces I need.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. What I decided to do was to declare my javascript variables (in the global scope) in the <head> of the containing page that needs the script. I assign them to the Custom Properties there, and then those values are available inside the script.